# Efficacy of pilates for fixing 'computer posture'

Tags: pilates

I have started pilates (on machines) with the intent of reversing my 'computer posture'.  y arms rotate inward, and my shoulders slope forward.  This is a well-known problem that comes from using computers for too much time.

I've finished 4 pilates sessions.  It seems like we focus on front muscles, like the stomach, and not as much on back muscles, which are what I'm hoping to fix.  The last thing I want to do is make the front muscles tighter by working them out, and ignoring the back muscles.  Is the issue that we've just begun (fourth session)?  Do I simply fail to see the work the pilates sessions are doing on my 'computer posture' affected muscles?  Or, is pilates simply not good for computer posture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any worthwhile pilates endeavour will ultimately strengthen your entire core.

But it's easy to forget that a lot of abdominal work also engages the entire core, which includes muscles in the lumbar region.

So to answer your question; I believe that either you're

- too early in your pilates journey, and are still learning more basic movements, or
- not aware of the entire scope of the exercises, and misinterpreting what they're good for

But yes, pilates is absolutely a good place to work on fixing bad posture due to extended periods of sitting.